# How can i link a img to start a video in fullscreen?

Tags: html, video, onclick, fullscreen

Im pretty new to html5, im learning at school.
I have a credits button (image) and what i want is when i click on the credits picture. a video should overlay everything thats on the Website.

I thought about redirect to another page with that Video on it. But i want it to happen flawless. Maybe with something like  Video.

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to be pretty hard to make in HTML only.

What you are trying to make is called 'Lightbox', if you have a little bit of Javascript knowledge you can try using this [jQuery plugin.](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) it's pretty simple to use and it has support for Video.